# How I create a dialog box for find a string

Tags: livecode

How I create a dialog box for find a string. I don't know how to create dialog box in LiveCode so that I am use ask command. is it the right way to create the dialog box in live code

```
global x
    on mouseUp
       ask "What is your name?"
       put it into x
       if x is  empty then 
          answer"wrong input"
       else
            repeat for each word ass in "MytextField"
          --repeat with each word myword in fld"MytextField"
             if  "MytextField" contains myword then 
                find x after "MytextField"
                   end if
          end repeat

          end if
    end mouseUp
    on mouseDown

    end mouseDown
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, but your handler has several syntax errors. Try this, in a button script, making sure that you have a field named "myTextField" with some pertinent text in it:

```
  on mouseUp
 ask "What is your name?"
 put it into x
 if x is  empty then 
  answer "wrong input"
 else
  repeat for each word myword in fld "MytextField"
     if  fld "MytextField" contains x then find x in fld "MytextField"
     exit to top
  end repeat
 end if
end mouseUp
```

Now there are several ways to do this same sort of thing. Please consider checking out the LC forum for additional resources.

Craig Newman

Comment: Its work. But each time I have to enter the input.can you tell me any method to solve it.